# When to run SYSPREP

Tags: windows, deployment

I am attempting to set up a computer using an answer file created by the WAIK and resetting the settings with SYSPREP and had a quick question. We are wanting to use Norton GHOST for our deployments. When do I run the sysprep? I figure it is after I get the computer all set up with the proper updates/software/drivers but I have not been able to find a direct answer to this online. Do i run it after everything is set up and the system is ready to be captured?

Comment: No. I had found a guide on it but it didn't specifically state when to do it.

Comment: Q: Do i run it after everything is set up and the system is ready to be captured? A: Yes.

Answer (score 3):

The steps are as follows:

1) Set the reference machine up the way you like it.
2) Sysprep the machine, selecting OOBE mode and shut down **(do *NOT* boot back into windows after this pont!)**
3) Boot the computer to your ghost media and capture the image.

Comment: MUCH appreciated!! And just to be clear sysprepping the machine and generalizing it will remove the domain, computer name, etc. correct?

Comment: You need to remove the computer from the domain before you sysprep, but otherwise yes. Sysprep /generalize will remove the computer name, network settings, license info, and device configuration from the machine.  It will not, however, remove the driver files themselves, which is nice because those devices for which you have installed drivers can then be redetected on the target hardware without prompting you for the install disk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Run SYSPREP after you have the image the way you want it (updates, configs, apps etc.).

Comment: Thank you SO much! I appreciate it! Do I run it in audit mode or in regular? I am not wanting to name the machine.

Comment: I only use OOBE, from what I understand, audit mode is more for OEM's that need to verify the image before shipping.

Comment: Do not use audit mode.  As @Somantra has stated, it is for OEMs generally.  It will also wipe some of the settings that the OOBE Sysprep doesn't mess with thus resulting in an image that doesn't fully match what you want.  One example of what audit mode does, is it wipes the local admin accounts.  Just FYI.